# Put "Chat" at the front of the <title> on chat

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, chat

Instead of

> User Experience | chat.stackexchange.com

can you change it to

> Chat - User Experience | Stack Exchange

or something like that?

I often keep the home page and chat open in tabs. This would make it easier to distinguish the two.

Comment: My concern here is that soon "Chat" is *all* that can be seen, for example when someone has multiple rooms open as separate tabs. Instead of seeing "[Tavern on] the Meta", "[Teachers Lo]unge" etc, they see "Chat - ", "Chat - " and "Chat - "

Comment: @MarcGravell Another option could be to supply a slightly different favicon so that if I choose to pin the tab (in Chrome), I can distinguish between a pinned version of the regular site and the chat.

Comment: @Rahul we did indeed discuss that internally (ages ago); let me remind Jin...

Comment: @Rahul to quote Jin: "i'm for it, i just haven't had the time to do it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just changed the room name to "UX Chat." Maybe we'll change it to something more creative. As long as the name doesn't start with "User Experience" the problem is solved.